# App update with device screen turned off - app doesn't start up correctly

Tags: android, screen, updates

I am currently doing an update of an app in the play store. Lets assume the play store contains V1, I am now working on V2.

Now I experience some problems during the update.

Depending on the state of the device screen during installation, I either can find the saved data in the shared preferences if the screen is turned on, I cannot find the saved data if the screen is turned off.

Clarification: V1 of my app is in the play store and currently installed on my device. V1 has saved some data in the preferences.
Now in Android Studio I press run, V2 gets installed on my device.
If I have the device screen turned on during installation everything will work, the V2 will replace the V1 app on the device and will start and find the V1 data.
If I have the device screen turned off during installation, the app will also be installed and when I turn on the screen the app will indeed start, but will not find the saved data and go on doing the wrong stuff.

Is this problem known? Is there a solution?

Comment: Hi ElDuderino, (Greetz from Big L :) ),usually, it shouldn´t have any effect because it´s an abnormal behaviour installing an app on a device when screen is off. This will never happen to your users. Maybe it has something to do with that poor documented doze mode on MM. As far as understand it, writing to a file (and maybe shared prefs) is not possible at app standby/doze mode.The scenario could be, that your app is falling into app standby directly and is not able to read/write the shared prefs fast enough, just an assumption.Have you controlled if the old shared preferences are still there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but ... I made a mistake. When the screen is turned off, Android will call onPause() right after onResume() and in onPause is where I do my saving. But the save data wasn't properly initialized du to going right into onPause(), so it saved a 0... yeah...my fault. Too many white russians maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was with me.
When the screen is turned off, Android will call onPause() right after onResume() and in onPause is where I do my saving. But the save data wasn't properly initialized du to going right into onPause(), so it saved a 0 which is wrong.